# Parsing Datepicker Data in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, parsing, datepicker

To begin with, I currently have code that looks like this in the view:

```
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="start1"> <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="end1">
```

I am using this to get the start and end date for how long a person will be staying in a hotel. Currently, for example, if a person chooses May 16, 2014 as the start date and May 24, 2014 as the end date, it is being stored in the database as one row as such:

'Name of Person'  'Room Number'  'Start Date'  'End Date'

So for the previous example, it would be stored as:

John Doe   100   5/16/2014   5/24/2014

Instead of this however, I want each row to represent a date as such:

John Doe  100  5/16/2014

John Doe  100  5/17/2014

John Doe  100  5/18/2014

and so on and so forth until 5/24/2014.

My question is this, how can I parse the data so that I can store the data as such?

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achieved using PHP's DateTime methods.

```
$from = new DateTime('2014-05-16');
$end = new DateTime('2014-05-24');
$end = $end->modify('+1 day'); 

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$range = new DatePeriod($from, $interval, $end);

foreach ($range as $date) {
    $row = array(
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'room' => 100,
        'date' => $date->format('n/d/Y')
    );
    print_r($row);
}
```

PS: Don't store `month/day/year` please. Use `day/month/year`. Confuses the heck out of people.

Edit: formatting nazi

Comment: When are we gonna universally accept YYYYMMDD?  Why is that not a universal timestamp?

Comment: Don't you mean YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS?

Comment: Kind of, but I don't see the need for the dashes.  But yes, EU, US etc. all write dates differently.

Comment: _“Don't store `month/day/year` please. Use `day/month/year`”_ – don’t store as _text_ at all, use an appropriate date type :-)

Comment: CBroe is right here. I meant to say "at least use day/month/year instead of that".